# Mysql temporary tables

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

Let's think that we created the temporary table. The docs says, that this table available for the current session. 
So, if there two or more connections with same username and password simultaneously, does the second connection have rights to access to the first data insterted by the frist connection?

Comment: they are different sessions, thus I think: no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a temporary table is limited to the scope of your database connection.

You can use the same temporary table in subsequent calls of the same database connection, but other connections cannot access it.

Even, another connection can create a temporary table with the same name, when you close your connection the temporary table will dissapear

Comment: So, if i create the temporary table "secret_data" and connected to mysql with the database username, for example, "root", the data inserted by the root would not be accessible for the second user logined as "root"???

Comment: no, the second connection couldn't access it. In the other hand, if you would like to access the data you insert by the first connection, then you'd need to insert a real table AND commit it.